# I have made functions that calculate based on input, however i have had to make 12 different functions based on the amount of inputs

Tags: python

I have my code

```
def Name(x1,y1,x2,y2,B):
      and so on
```

I have made a multiply of these depending on how many values i have x1,y1-x14,y14 but I was wondering if I could use the if function to shorten it and have the code recognize which function to use by the n value next to the letter

```
def Name(x1,y1....xn,yn)
 if n=12
uses Name12
```

sample of my code

```
    def arb_2odds(x1,y1,x2,y2,B):
    arb_o1=(100*y1)/(x1+y1)
    arb_o2=(100*y2)/(y2+x2)
    arb_total=arb_o1+arb_o2
    bet_for_01=(round((B*arb_o1)/arb_total,2))
    bet_for_02=(round((B*arb_o2)/arb_total,2))
    payout_O1=round(((bet_for_01/y1)*x1+bet_for_01),2)
    payout_O2=round(((bet_for_02/y2)*x2+bet_for_02),2)
    Profit_O1=round(payout_O1-B,2)
    Profit_O2=round(payout_O2-B,2)
    roi=100-arb_total

    print("//ARB calculations is",arb_total,"//the ROI is:", roi,"percent//")
    print("//Place",round(bet_for_01,2),"Euros on the first Odds//Place", round(bet_for_02,2),"Euros on the second Odds//")
    print("//If the first odds win the payout is:",payout_O1,"Euros, and the profit is:",Profit_O1,"Euros")
    print("//If the second odds win the payout is:",payout_O2,"Euros, and the profit is:",Profit_O2,"Euros")
#3 outcome games
def arb_3odds(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,B):
    arb_o1=(100*y1)/(x1+y1)
    arb_o2=(100*y2)/(y2+x2)
    arb_o3=(100*y3)/(y3+x3)
    arb_total=arb_o1+arb_o2+arb_o3
    bet_for_01=round((B*arb_o1)/arb_total,2)
    bet_for_02=round((B*arb_o2)/arb_total,2)
    bet_for_03=round((B*arb_o3)/arb_total,2)
    toatl_payout=(bet_for_01*x1+y1*bet_for_01)/y1
    profit=toatl_payout-B
    roi=100-arb_total
    
    print("//ARB calculations is",arb_total,"//the ROI is:", roi,"percent//")
    print("//Place",round(bet_for_01,3),"Euros on the first Odds//Place",round(bet_for_02,3),"Euros on the second Odds//Place",round(bet_for_03,3),"Euros on the third Odds//")
    print("//The total payout is",round(toatl_payout,3),"//The profit is",round(profit,3),"Euros//")
```

Comment: what about `*args`?

Answer (score 1):

My approch:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from typing import Sequence
from random import randint

Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

def arb_odds(points: Sequence[Point], B: int):
    arbs = [(100 * p.y) / (p.x + p.y) for p in points]
    arb_total = sum(arbs)
    bets = [round((B * arb) / arb_total , 2) for arb in arbs]
    roi = 100 - arb_total

    print( f"//ARB calculations is {arb_total} //the ROI is: {roi} percent//")

    if (length := len(points)) % 2 == 0:
        payouts = [round(((bet / p.y) * p.x + bet), 2) for bet, p in zip(bets, points) ]
        profits = [round(payout - B, 2) for payout in payouts]

        # Use `humanize` package if you want nicer ordinal number string display
        print(" ".join(
            [f"//Place {round(bet, 3)} Euros on the {i+1}th Odds" for i, bet in enumerate(bets)]
        ))
        print("\n".join(
            [
                f"//If the {i+1}th odds win the payout is: {payout} Euros, and the profit is: {profit} Euros"
                for i, (payout, profit) in enumerate(zip(payouts, profits))
            ]
        ))
    else:
        total_payout = (bets[0] * points[0].x + points[0].y *bets[0]) / points[0].y
        profit = total_payout - B
        print(" ".join(
            [f"//Place {round(bet, 3)} Euros on the {i+1}th Odds" for i, bet in enumerate(bets)]
        ))
        print(f"//The total payout is {round(total_payout, 3)} //The profit is {round(profit, 3)} Euros//")   
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    even_points = tuple(Point(randint(1, 10), randint(1, 10)) for _ in range(4))
    odd_points = tuple(Point(randint(1, 10), randint(1, 10)) for _ in range(7))

    print(even_points)
    print(odd_points)

    arb_odds(even_points, 6)
    arb_odds(odd_points, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep a consistent functional form, it would be better to take a list of input tuples as the first argument. You can then rewrite the function something like this:

```
ORDINAL_WORDS = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]  # expand as needed

def arb_odds(inputs, B):
    arb_total = sum((100 * y) / (x + y) for x, y in inputs)
    print(f"//ARB calculations is {arb_total} //the ROI is: {100 - arb_total} percent//")
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(inputs):
        bet = 100 * B * y / (x + y) / arb_total
        print(f"//Place {bet:.2f} Euros on {ORDINAL_WORDS[i]} odds")
```

You would call this function like this:

```
arb_odds([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)], B)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#betting and hedging
def arb(*args):
    N_arguments =len(args)
    if N_arguments == 5:
        arb_2odds(*args)
    if N_arguments == 3:
        Tester(*args)
    if N_arguments == 7:
        arb_3odds(*args)
    if N_arguments == 9:
        arb_4odds(*args)
    if N_arguments ==11:
        arb_5odds(*args)
    if N_arguments == 13:
        arb_6odds(*args)
    if N_arguments == 15:
        arb_7odds(*args)
    if N_arguments ==17:
    arb_8odds(*args)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
def add_all(*args):
      total=0
      for i in args:
           total+=i
      return total
```

Comment: Can use `sum(args)` instead of the loop to get the total.
Additionally, might be a good idea to handle exceptions as the dynamic type of the objects in the `args` might not allow "sum"-ing up.

Comment: That wouldnt be possible as i am not summing everything together, ill supply a sample of two bits of my code